# Changing multiple cells values using a command Button

Tags: excel, vba, button, command

I am trying to figure out how to change 3 cells on 3 different sheets to the same value as the Command Button Caption. I have managed to get it working if there is only one command but can't seem to get it to work on multiple commands.

```
Private Sub CmdSME100_Click()

    Worksheets("Calculator").Range("I1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
    Worksheets("Tariff Matrix").Range("A1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
    Worksheets("Bolt-On Matrix").Range("A1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption

End Sub
```

As it stands this is the code i am trying to get to work. and i can't seem to figure out why it wont work on all the different sheets.

I need this to work as the cells that i am asking the code to change then trigger an auto filter.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try "activating" the sheets. Considering "Calculator" is Sheet1, "Tariff Matrix" is Sheet2 and "Bolt-On Matrix" is Sheet 3;

```
Private Sub CmdSME100_Click()
Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.Range("A1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
Sheet2.Activate
Sheet2.Range("A1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
Sheet3.Activate
Sheet3.Range("A1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a sheet variable to access them

```
Private Sub CmdSME100_Click()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Range("I1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(2)
    ws.Range("A1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(3)
    ws.Range("A1") = Me.CmdSME100.Caption
End Sub
```

If your worksheets aren't reliably in the same index you can search for them by name.

The code would look something like this.

```
'Find the worksheet named *BBCOV*
iFoundWorksheet = 0
For iIndex = 1 To Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(iIndex)
    If UCase(ws.Name) = "BBCOV-PURGED" Then
        iFoundWorksheet = iIndex
        Exit For
    End If
Next iIndex
If iFoundWorksheet = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No worksheet was found with the name BBCOV-PURGED (this is not case sensetive). Aborting."
    GoTo Abort
End If
Set ws = Application.Worksheets(iFoundWorksheet)
ws.Activate
```

Comment: I forgot to change your Worksheets("Calculator") to ws.  Change had been made.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can grab the caption quite like that.

Try this instead:

`ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption`

So...

```
Private Sub CmdSME100_Click()
  Worksheets("Calculator").Range("I1") = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption
  Worksheets("Tariff Matrix").Range("A1") = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption
  Worksheets("Bolt-On Matrix").Range("A1") = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you still having problems with this issue?

Comment: yes but i think this may have something to do with my auto filter.